# Page scrolls up on clicking of image in content editor webpart in Chrome

Tags: 2013, 2010, chrome

I have a content editor webpart.

When I edit the webpart and click on the Image, the page scrolls up in Chrome.

This doesnt happen in IE

I haven't added any special code for this, is this the default behaviour?

Comment: on which image when you click you experience this kind of behavior?

Comment: This is problem with SharePoint 2013. It happens at many other location too. eg.If you publish an InfoPath form with Date control in it and click on the calendar icon(which is image) in Chrome. The page scrolls up. It looks like some JS error.